# Replace field values with arcpy update cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am a bit new for the arcpy. I have a database table so I can't use field calculator. so I would like to use Python script for solving the issue.

```
import arcpy
... # Your input feature class
... table = r'D:\werk_map.gdb\test_gw_bsl'
... # Start an update cursor and change values from 0 to 100 in a field called "your_field"
... with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, "Thickness") as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         if row[0] == "0,1":
...             row[0] = "0,5"
...         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

I just want to replace all “0,1” values in the thickness field with “0,5”.
The above written arcpy script is running without error but not changing the values in the table.
I think may be it has do something with the comma in the field value.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the new user [tour].

Comment: After your for statement try: `print row[0]` to see what is actually being picked up by the cursor

Answer (score 2):

First I don't see why you can't do this using the Field Calculator - it works on Database Tables as well as Feature Classes and Layers.

Now onto your script - you are very close.  Your cursor `if` is checking for `"0,1"` and wanting to replace with `"0,5"` - the quote-marks around it means it is looking for text but your values are numbers, stored in a numeric type field.  Python won't find text in a numeric field.

Also, because of how python treats commas, you will need to use a decimal point `.` in your code (it won't affect how it is stored in your table):

```
import arcpy
    # Your input feature class
    table = r'D:\werk_map.gdb\test_gw_bsl'
    # Start an update cursor and change values from 0 to 100 in a field called "your_field"
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, "Thickness") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == 0.1:
                row[0] = 0.5
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, Midavalo for you reply. i tried your suggestion but its not working. The field thickness accepts only ", " commas instead of "." decimal points( float nummer). The field calculator is greyed out. I think its a relational database table.

Comment: Just curious as to how you know its a numeric field? I would have thought since it contained a comma that it would have to be text?

Comment: @GISKid The values are right-aligned in the screenshot.  Numbers are (usually) right-aligned, text is left-aligned.  I could be wrong though, other countries/regions may have the left/right align settings different than what I use

Comment: yes its a float numeric field

Comment: yes exactly we use commas instead of decimal points in numeric field

Comment: @Ram Did you try my suggested code?  My understanding (and my testing) is that the database should still accept it with the decimal point and then save it correctly.  Can you confirm the type of database?  You mention it may be a relational database however your code snippet has a `.gdb` not a `.sde` connection which would suggest a File geodatabase.  If the Field Calculator is greyed out you may just need to Start Editing on the table to enable it.

Comment: @Midavalo yes i tried your code but its not working. i am now using a .gdb. for testing the script.  but i want to use the python script to .sde. in the .gdb i can use field calculator and i just checked .sde if i started edit session i can use field calculator.

Comment: OP is probably using the comma as [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point), which is purely a display setting.